# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: emulation currently requires hardware acceleration

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am missing the folder Intel in exteras and I have problem with emulator.

I am getting this error

Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed `HAXM` installer on your `SDKManager` :

[image]

after you download it and make sure you run the setup located in: "SDK_FOLDER"\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe "

Note: in Android Studio, the command "intelhaxm.exe" has been changed to "intelhaxm-android.exe"

If you get the error "VT not supported" during the installation disable Hyper-V on windows features. You can execute this command dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V. You will also need "Virtualization Technology" to be enabled on your BIOS .